# Langchain agent does not always use the tool correctly

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, langchain, py-langchain, large-language-model

Sometimes the Langchain Agent entering the custom tool with the input:
"Invalid or incomplete response"

Even if the LLM seems to use the tool correctly.

Any idea why and how to fix that ?

I would point out that sometimes everything works as expected.

My tool:

````
@tool
def saveEvent(event: str) -> str:
  """Use it to save an event in my calendar. \
    The input should be a VCALENDAR string and be formated as follow:
    '''
      BEGIN:VCALENDAR
      VERSION:2.0
      BEGIN:VEVENT
      SUMMARY: ```the name of the event in french if you don't know the name, create one limited to 10 words```
      DESCRIPTION: ```Description of the event in french, if you don't know the description, summarize the message```
      DTSTART: ```Start date of the event, use the paris timezone and format as follow: AAAAMMJJDhhmmssZ```
      DTEND: ```End date of the event use the paris timezone and format as follow: AAAAMMJJDhhmmssZ```
      LOCATION: ```the location of the event```
      CATEGORIES: ```the categories of the event```
      END:VEVENT
      END:VCALENDAR
    '''
    This function will return 'OK' if the event is correctlly saved or 'ERROR' if there is an error."""
  resp = calendar.save_event(event)
  if resp:
    return 'OK'
  else:
    return 'ERROR'
````

The agent:

```
tools = load_tools(['python_repl'], llm=llm)
agent= initialize_agent(
    tools + [saveEvent], 
    llm, 
    agent=AgentType.CHAT_ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
    handle_parsing_errors=True,
    max_iterations=3,
    verbose = True)

messages = agent_prompt_template.format_prompt(text=message)
response = agent(messages.to_string())
```

The console output:

````
[llm/end] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 2:chain:LLMChain > 3:llm:GPTLLM] [10.44s] Exiting LLM run with output:
{
  "generations": [
    [
      {
        "text": "Thought: I need to format the event information provided in the JSON into a VCALENDAR string according to the given template. Once I have the formatted event, I can use the 'saveEvent' tool to add it to the calendar.\n\nAction:\n```json\n{\n  \"action\": \"saveEvent\",\n  \"action_input\": \"BEGIN:VCALENDAR\\nVERSION:2.0\\nBEGIN:VEVENT\\nSUMMARY:Festival ForroDiois\\nDESCRIPTION:Marilia Cervi est une des trois prof invités au Festival ForroDiois. Elle partagera sa danse avec nous le samedi 17 juin et dimanches 18 juin (3 cours de 1h30 chacun).\\nDTSTART:20230617T000000Z\\nDTEND:20230617T020000Z\\nLOCATION:Non spécifié\\nCATEGORIES:danse,festival\\nEND:VEVENT\\nEND:VCALENDAR\"\n}\n```\n\n",
        "generation_info": null
      }
    ]
  ],
  "llm_output": null,
  "run": null
}
[chain/end] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 2:chain:LLMChain] [10.44s] Exiting Chain run with output:
{
  "text": "Thought: I need to format the event information provided in the JSON into a VCALENDAR string according to the given template. Once I have the formatted event, I can use the 'saveEvent' tool to add it to the calendar.\n\nAction:\n```json\n{\n  \"action\": \"saveEvent\",\n  \"action_input\": \"BEGIN:VCALENDAR\\nVERSION:2.0\\nBEGIN:VEVENT\\nSUMMARY:Festival ForroDiois\\nDESCRIPTION:Marilia Cervi est une des trois prof invités au Festival ForroDiois. Elle partagera sa danse avec nous le samedi 17 juin et dimanches 18 juin (3 cours de 1h30 chacun).\\nDTSTART:20230617T000000Z\\nDTEND:20230617T020000Z\\nLOCATION:Non spécifié\\nCATEGORIES:danse,festival\\nEND:VEVENT\\nEND:VCALENDAR\"\n}\n```\n\n"
}
[tool/start] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 4:tool:_Exception] Entering Tool run with input:
"Invalid or incomplete response"
[tool/end] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 4:tool:_Exception] [0.111ms] Exiting Tool run with output:
"Invalid or incomplete response"
````

Comment: Use Chatgpt3.5, opensource LLM is not well trained for agents